# How to allow all lower-level domain based on the second-level domain in uBlock Origin?

Tags: domain, ublock-origin

Many sites have third-level domain: **en**.wikipedia.com, **academia**.stackexchange.com, **translator**.google.com. I have a universal dynamic filter:

```
* * 3p-script block
```

and would like to *individually* allow *all* domains from Wikipedia, Stack Exchange or Google to load 3rd party scripts. But it seems that [dynamic filtering](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Dynamic-filtering:-rule-syntax) doesn't support wildcard on the domain.

How to allow all lower-level domain based on the second-level domain in uBlock Origin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can [whitelist](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/How-to-whitelist-a-web-site) them. It even support regex.

Emphasis mine:

> - `example.com`: whitelist all pages from `example.com` **or above** (i.e. `example.com`, `www.example.com`).

The downside is that you can't use filters to block ads on whitelisted sites.

Answer (score 0):

make your filter as usual, but without the subdomain, e.g.:

`en.wikipedia.org`

becomes

`wikipedia.org`